# Cordova, get all pictures from the camera roll

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am building an app with ionic and cordova. I managed to access the camera roll and give user a possibility to manually select one photo. 
However, I am not sure how to access all of the photos automatically, without human interaction. I would llike to append them to an array in my code for further processing.
I found this plugin, but it does not work for me:

https://github.com/driftyco/cordova-camera-roll

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can Maximum select 10 image at a time.

Use multiple image picker plugin to select upto 10 images.

Github link- https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker

Installation -

```
phonegap plugin add https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker.git

cordova plugin add https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-imagePicker.git
```

Example -

```
window.imagePicker.getPictures(
    function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            console.log('Image URI: ' + results[i]);
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error);
    }, {
        maximumImagesCount: 10,
        width: 800
    }
);
```

Comment: Thank you. But are you sure that I can use it without opening the camera roll selector? What I want to achieve in my app is the following:
A user accesses a menu called 'Gallery' and they immediately see a gallery of their camera roll pictures which is presented by my app (not a native camera roll selector).

Comment: This app will open your gallery. One can select image from any folder in gallery. It doesn't restrict user to particular folder.

Comment: Then it is not what I want. I would like to gather all the user's pictures without interacting with them...

Comment: I think it's possible if you create a plugin that uses ALAssetsLibrary

Comment: @nehil mistry bro I want to restrict my user to select images from my camera roll only is there any way for it?